# Using flow chart or diagram for routines across programs

Tags: scripting, refactoring, flowchart

I have a busy set of routines to validate or download the current client application.  It starts with a Windows desktop shortcut that invokes a .WSF file.  This calls on several .VBS files, an .INI for settings, and potentially a .BAT file.  Some of these script documents have internal functions.  The final phase opens a Microsoft Access database, which entails an AutoExec macro, which kicks off some VBA, including a form which has a load routine of its own in VBA.

None of this detail is specifically important (so please don't add a VBA tag, OR criticize my precious complexity).  The point is I have a variety of tools and containers and they may be functionally nested.

I need better techniques for parsing that in a flow chart.  Currently I rely on any or all of the following:

- a distinct color
- a big box that encloses a routine
- the classic 'transfer of control' symbol
- perhaps an explanatory call-out

Shouldn't I increase my flow charting vocabulary?  Tutorials explain the square, the diamond, the circle, and just about nothing more.  Surely FC can help me deal with **these sorts of things:**

1. The plethora of script types lets me answer different needs, and I want to indicate tool/language.
2. A sub-routine could result in an abort of the overall task, or an error, and I want to show the handling of that by (or consequences for) higher-level "enclosing" routines.
3. I want to distinguish "internal" sub-routines from ones in a different script file.
4. Concurrent script processing could become critical, so I want to note that.
5. The .INI file lets me provide all routines with persistent values.  How is that charted?
6. A function may have an argument(s) and a return value/reference ... I don't know how to effectively cite even that.

Please provide guidance or point me to a extra-helpful resource.  If you recommend an analysis tool set (like UML, which I haven't gotten the hang of yet), please also tell me where I can find a good introduction.

I am not interested in software.  Please consider this a white board exercise.

Comment: I haven't actually seen a flow chart in the wild for about 25 years. I really would not recommend them.

Comment: Thanks ... Then perhaps you have the answer to my question.

Comment: Not really, because I don't understand what it is. The best documentation for code is normally the code itself, with comments, and with an overview document/tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: I consider FC essential for resolving logical errors.  If that's old-school, then I may enjoy converting to whatever is new-school.  But in any case that may help you understand my felt need or working goal.

Comment: Flowcharts cannot resolve logical errors, because they are not rigorous and have no grammar.

Comment: "The best documentation for code is normally the code itself, with comments, and with an overview document/tutorial ..."  Are you proposing this is the solution?  Is it rigorous, grammatical?  I'm not trying to challenge you; just probing for some take-away help.

Comment: Well, the code is certainly rigorous and grammatical because it must be compilable. The problem is that there is no guarantee that a flowchart matches up with what the code actually does, and that flow charts become unwieldy for anything except the most trivial programs.

Comment: "no guarantee matches up ... unwieldy ..."  Yes, these are problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussion of the question suggests flowcharts are not useful or accurate.

Accuracy depends on how the flow charts are constructed.  If they are constructed manually, they are like any other manually built document and will be out of date almost instantly; that makes hand-constructed flowcharts really useless, which is why people tend to like looking at the code.

[The rest of this response violate's the OPs requirement of "not interested in software (to produce flowcharts)" because I think that's the only way to get them in some kind of useful form.]

If the flowcharts are derived from the code by an an appropriate language-accurate analysis tool, they will be accurate.  See examples at http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html  These examples are semantically precise although the pages there don't provide the exact semantics, but that's just a documetation detail.

It is hard to find such tools :-}  especially if you want flowcharts that span multiple languages, and multiple "execution paradigms" (OP wants his INI files included; they are some kind of implied assignment statements, and I'm pretty sure he'd want to model SQL actions which don't flowchart usefully because they tend to be pure computation over tables).

It is also unclear that such flowcharts are useful.  The examples at the page I provided should be semiconvincing; if you take into account all the microscopic details (e.g., the possiblity of an ABORT control flow arc emanating from every subroutine call [because each call may throw an exception]) these diagrams get horrendously big, fast.  The fact that the diagrams are space-consuming (boxes, diamonds, lines, lots of whitespace) aggravates this pretty badly. Once they get big, you literally get lost in space following the arcs. Again, a good reason for people to avoid flowcharts for entire systems.  (The other reason people like text languages is they can in fact be pretty dense; you can get a lot on a page with a succinct language, and wait'll you see APL :)

They might be of marginal help in individual functions, if the function has complex logic.

I think it unlikely that you are going to get language accurate analyzers that produce flowcharts for all the languages you want, that such anlayzers can compose their flowcharts nicely (you want JavaScript invoking C# running SQL ...?)

What you might hope for is a compromise solution: display the code with various hyper links to the other artifacts referenced.   You still need the ability to produce such hyperlinked code (see http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/JavaBrowser.html for one way this might work), but you also need hyperlinks across the language boundaries.

I know of no tools that presently do that. And I doubt you have the interest or willpower to build such tools on your own.

Comment: That's a terrific analysis, though I may point out it doesn't match the OP ("I'm not interested in software").  From that, I would conclude you consider the OP to be not answerable as given, which I respect; and of course I realize I prolly do lack interest or willpower.  I remain interested in seeing whether anyone thinks an expanded flow-chart vocabulary or better technique would help me (I mean as a white-board exercise). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're right, I got a bit carried away with "software to do this", but I thought I made it clear early in my response as to why: hand-construction of such documents mostly leads to stale paper ("whiteboard scribbles") so this path just doesn't work long term.  If your *only* goal is to draw on a whiteboard for the purposes of a technical meeting, then in fact flowcharts are pretty much good enough.  The only thing I'd add would be "exception" arcs from computation nodes saying, "if this fails, follow this exception arc to ...".  ....

Comment: ... but I don't see how a whiteboard analysis can possibly take into account all the complexity you seem to want to model in a useful way.  And if you want to handle all that complexity, I think you're back to tools that are hard to get.